# textarea value not displaying on page after reload

Tags: javascript, html

Pretty simple script but somehow it does not work. I have a text area and a button. The javascript creates an array from textarea text, which i want to use to another text fields. The thing is, that the script generates the array just only first time after page reload. The same value is displayed even if you change the text in the textarea. Any solution?

```
 <textarea id="rev">TESTING...</textarea>
        <div id="test"></div>

        <button id="button" onclick="createArr()">button</button>



 function createArr() {

    var arr = new Array();
    var txt = $('#rev').html();
    $.each(txt.split('\n'), function (i, value) {
        if (value != "") {
            arr.push(value);
        }

    });

    $("#firstname1").text(arr[0]);
}
```

Comment: `$('#rev').html()` grabs what's between `<textarea>` and `</textarea>`, you need the *value* though: `$('#rev').val()`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @ChrisG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 function createArr() {

    var arr = new Array();
    var txt = $('#rev').val();
    $.each(txt.split('\n'), function (i, value) {
        if (value != "") {
            arr.push(value);
        }

    });

    $("#firstname1").text(arr);
}
```